# javascript global variable breaks chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, global-variables

I have my javascript code running fine on firefox, but doesn't work on Chrome. It said my global variable named frames is not defined. I checked my code carefully, and there's nothing wrong with it. It also worked fine on firefox and other browsers.

Is there anything to do with the global variable in chrome?

.apsillers is right. Problem solved!

Comment: Could you post the relevant code, perhaps on jsfiddle?

Comment: Chrome's not wrong, your code is.  Please post it.

Comment: The global variable `window.frames` is a pre-existing browser construct.  If you are making a new global variable named `frames`, you are clobbering the one that exists already.  Incidentally, FF and IE do not allow you to overwrite `frames`, whereas Chrome does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variable `frames` is a pre-existing browser construct. (It is actually an alias for `window`.) If you are making a new global variable named `frames`, you are trying to clobber the one that exists already.  However, Firefox and Internet Explorer do not allow you to overwrite `frames`, whereas Chrome does.  You are probably accidentally destroying or rewriting `frames`, but only Chrome is actually letting you do it.

If you post your code, we can know for sure.

Comment: yes, that's the problem. I changed my global variable named frames and it worked perfectly in Chrome. Thanks so muchhhhhhhhhhhhh...